# Hide Output of Oracle SQL in UNIX

Tags: sql, oracle, output, hide

I have following code in UNIX to call DB sql,

EXECUTE  {Some Package};

@{path from where i am calling a sql}

here i want to see output of SQL **only** not what package return, pls advice.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  `EXECUTE` implies that you have a SQL*Plus script.  You can't execute a package, you can execute a method within a package (you can execute a procedure within a package for example).  It isn't obvious to me what "what package return" means or what you are seeing that you don't want to see.  Is the procedure, for example, writing to `dbms_output`?

Comment: it is a package that we need to run Once every time we connect to database. so this package returns, PL/SQL procedure completed successfully. I want to hide this message,  PL/SQL procedure completed successfully, and show only what SQL returns. 
what package returns isn't important to me but SQL output is important.